# Upper bound for the expectation of a random variable times an indicator function

Tags: probability, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have a random variable $X$. Is there any way of deriving an upper bound of the following expectation:
$$E[X * \mathbf{1}_{X\ge x_0}],$$

where $\mathbf{1}_{()}$ is an 0-1 indicator function, and $x_0$ is a constant.

Specifically, I am trying to see if we can derive a Jensen's inequality-style upper bound, however the original Jensen's inequality certainly doesn't work.

Clearly, $X$ and $\mathbf{1}_{X\ge x_0}$ are positively correlated, and we have $E[X * \mathbf{1}_{X\ge x_0}] \ge E[X]* E[\mathbf{1}_{X\ge x_0}]$, which is the opposite direction that I want to pursue.

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz gives you the following bound: $\mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{1}_{A}] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X| \mathbb{1}_{A}] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2] \Pr(A)}$. Not sure how tight this will be for your application.